# Why cin.clear() is not reseting the failbit state?

Tags: c++, cin

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  int const size = 10;
  char input_1[size];
  char input_2[size];
  cout << "Enter input 1: " << endl;
  cin.get(input_1, size);
  cin.get();
  cin.clear();
  cout << "Enter input 2: " << endl;
  cin.get(input_2,size);
  cout << "input_2 = " << input_2 << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT1**
~/cplusplus $ ./conundrum.o

Enter input 1:

qwe

Enter input 2:

asd

input_2 = asd

**OUTPUT 2**

~/cplusplus $ ./conundrum.o

Enter input 1:

Enter input 2:

input_2 =

~/cplusplus $

---

When I enter continuous stream of characters, this program outputs as expected. OUTPUT 1 shows the expected output. But when I only hit enter for the first input this code does not ask for input_2 and throws an empty input_2, shown in OUTPUT 2. As per my understanding, the newline character should have been annihilated by cin.get() and the failbit set to some abnormal state (after having nothing to store in input_1) should be reset by cin.clear() to get ready for the second cin.get(input_2,...). Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should make this change

```
cin.get(input_1, size);
cin.clear();
cin.get();
```

In your code `cin.get()` fails because the fail bit is already set.

Comment: Thanks. Now I see where's the problem.